# expectations of limits of norms of convergent r.v.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Assume we have two sequences of random vectors $(X_{n})_{n > 1}$ and $(Y_{n})_{n > 1}$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ and defined on the same probability space. Also, we know that $(X_{n})_{n > 1}$ converges weakly to some random $X$ and $E[||X_{n}||_{2}^{2}] < \infty$ for all $n$.

Next, for some fixed continuous function $g: \mathbb{R}^{k}\times \mathbb{R}^{k} \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ let $Z_{n}$ be the following random variable

$$
Z_{n} = g(X_{n}, Y_{n})
$$
and assume there exists $n_{0}$ such that for all $n>n_{0}$ the following holds almost surely
$$
Z_{n} \leq C ||X_{n}||_{2}^{2},
$$
for some constant $C$.

Is the following correct?

$$
E[\limsup_{n}g(X_{n}, Y_{n})] \leq C \, E[||X||_{2}^{2}].
$$

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct. Draw $X_n=n$ with probability $1/n$ and $0$ with probability $1-1/n$, independently for all $n$. Pick $Z_n=X_n$. Then:

- $(X_n)$ converges in distribution to $X\equiv 0$.
- $(X_n\ge n)$ is a sequence of independent events whose sum of probabilities diverges, so by [the second Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result) $(X_n\ge n)$ occurs infinitely often almost surely. In particular $\lim\sup X_n=+\infty$ almost surely.

So $X_n\le X_n^2$, $\mathsf{E} \lim\sup X_n=+\infty$ and $\mathsf{E} X^2=0$.